# How to add special symbols in the page title, using zend framework?

Tags: zend-framework

In zend framework, using headTitle() ignores the special characters like trademark etc.  How to add those?

Comment: I never figured out what hoops they wanted me to jump through either.  Have everything using utf-8 and still strips it out.  Assuming your encoding is set correctly and it still don't work extend Zend_View_Helper_HeadTitle and hack out the escaping crap in toString().  Unsure where `_autoEscaping` is derived.  Better answers?

Comment: I finally ended up doing a simple echo for the title :( was in a hurry

Comment: What do you mean by ignores the special characters? Do you want to disable escaping? `echo $this->headTitle('&copy; Copright')->setAutoEscape(false);`